# Parse JSON with Alamofire

Tags: json, swift, http, swift2

Since five hours I have tried to parse a json response.
The response looks like this.

```
{
   "USD_PHP" =     {
       val = "45.7295";
   };
}
```

I use this method in swift2 to make the request.

```
func GetRate() -> Float
{
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v3/convert?q=USD_PHP&compact=y")
        .responseJSON { response in
            if let json = response.result.value {
                print(json)
                let usd = json as! NSDictionary
                print(usd)
                let dict = usd["USD_PHP"] as! NSDictionary
                let val = dict.objectForKey("val") as! NSString //?
                print(val)

                // ?
                return Float(val as String)
            }
    }

    return 0.0
}
```

the *print(val)* prints *Optional(45.7295)*

But I don't know how to return this value as a float.
Has anyone an idea?

Comment: Is it `45.7295` not a float?

Comment: You could try [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON), it works well with Alamofire.

Comment: yes swiftyjson should be the obvious choice because it makes your life a lot better.

Answer (score 1):

```
if let value = Float(val as String) {
   return value
} else {
   return 0.0
}
```

But actually it doesn't help you because `responseJSON { response in` is asynchronous callback and you definitely have to read about it.

Comment: It works for me!
 if let value = Float((val?.stringValue)!) {
                        result = value
                    } else {
                        result = 0.0
                    }